# Catholic Apocalypse Short Story - can't remember the title

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, apocalypse

I'm trying to remember the title of a short story about the Apocalypse written by a Catholic priest. Can you please help me? It's NOT *Lord of the World* by Monsignor Robert Hugh Benson. It's a much shorter story, maybe a novella.

We read this in seminary. It details the judgment of the Catholics, Protestants, and Jews at the end of time. One of those groups is led by the Elder John, the Apostle John who never died but has been hiding and secretly guiding the Church through history — my favorite element.

Comment: Probably not Robert Sheckley's [The Battle](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58544), but you might enjoy it anyway.

Comment: I thought for sure this was going to be [A Canticle for Leibowitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Canticle_for_Leibowitz)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Possibly [A Short Story of the Antichrist](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24493031) by Vladimir Solovyov.

It is along the lines you describe. *Elder John* is introduced in the paragraph:

> The real, though unofficial, leader of the Orthodox was the Elder John, very well known among the Russian people. His official status was that of a bishop “in retirement,” yet he did not live in any monastery, but constantly travelled about. There were strange legends about him. Some people maintained that he was the risen Fyodor Kuzmich, that is, the Emperor Alexander I, who had been born some three centuries before. Others went further and said that he was the real Elder John, i.e. the apostle John the Divine who had never died and of late appeared openly. He himself said nothing about his origin or his youth. He was very old but still vigorous, with yellowish and even greenish white curly hair and beard, tall and thin, with full and slightly rosy cheeks, lively bright eyes and a touchingly kind expression in his face and voice; he always wore a white cassock and cloak.

Comment: Yes! Thank you 

Comment: @ScottSmith Please will you click on the tick mark to the left of my answer to mark it as accepted. Thanks :-)

Comment: Sure, sorry! I'm still learning the ropes :)